# Android Broadcast Receiver start from text message keyword

Tags: android, text, sms, broadcastreceiver

How to set keyword to initiate Broadcast Receiver from text message? I got my Broadcast Receiver working, problem is it starts activity on receiving any text message and I just need it to start on receiving 1 or 2 keywords "Hotel and/or House" how  do i do this .... Thank you. Below is my code

-manifest-
" 
    
     
    
 "

-actual receiver class-
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
        smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    //show first message
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    //and then start an activity

    Intent i = new Intent(context,AppActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Here is what is in my mainfest                              <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BroadcastReceiver` listens to Intents based on an `<intent-filter>`. The [data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) filter doesn't provide kind of filtering you're asking for because it doesn't filter on `SmsMessage.getMessage()`. What you can do in addition to listening for an SMS is scan each message for the keyword and then start the desired activity.

Comment: As you create the SmsMessage objects put a second copy of the message in a StringBuilder. Then check if the StringBuilder object contains the word you're searching for. If it does have the keyword, start the activity, if not do nothing.